# Python and igraph deepcopy : object.__new__(igraph.Edge) is not safe, use igraph.Edge.__new__()

Tags: python, igraph

I'm trying to `deepcopy` my igraph object like this :

```
copy.deepcopy(graph)
```

Where graph is igraph object, a full graph with few vertices. But I get this error :

```
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 93, in __newobj__
        return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
    TypeError: object.__new__(igraph.Edge) is not safe, use igraph.Edge.__new__()
```

Does any one know what the problem is and how should I copy an igraph object?

Comment: Seems to work for me in Python 2.7 on a Mac (I tried: ``g=Graph.GRG(100, 0.2); g2=deepcopy(g)``). Can you post a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can try pickling the object you want to copy and then unpickling it into another variable:

```
from cPickle import dumps, loads
g2 = loads(dumps(g))
```